# Matrix multiplication over specific dimensions in tensorflow (or numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensor

I hope I'm not missing anything obvious here, but I've scoured the [inter-webs](https://xkcd.com/181/) to no avail, and finally come to ask here...
Here's a really dry and simple description of what I'd like to do:
Say I've got a tensor of shape `(20, 40, 3, 5)`, and another tensor of shape `(20, 40, 5, 7)`. The first two dimension sizes are to be kept as are, and are purposely identical for the two tensors. The *last* two dimensions on the other hand, are to be (matrix-)multiplied, `matmul` style. Meaning my resulting tensor would be of shape `(20, 40, 3, 7)`. How can that be done??
I realize I can theoretically just loop over the first two dimensions and use `tf.matmul()` directly, but that's an absolute no-go due to runtime, efficiency, model-trainer and GPU world-wide protests, and my conscience if that's of any weight :-).

I've unfortunately disregarded as "not what I need" the following options:
[`tf.tensordot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot) would give me an output of shape `(20, 40, 3, 20, 40, 7)`. No good.
[`tf.scan`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scan) is only good for the first dimension if I'm reading it correctly (suitable for RNNs maybe? Not my case anyhow).
[`tf.matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matmul) works for tensors of rank >= 2, but works like `@` over the last and first dimensions respectively. Again, not my case.

So again - how can this be done?
A `numpy` answer that helps me get in the right direction would also be very helpful, but I'll need a `tf` implementation at the end of the day.

Thanks in advance, and sorry if I'm missing something dumb.

---

The following is closer to what I need, but less clear and so is being written separately:
The first two dimensions are spatial dimensions of an image. The last two are actually square matrices, obtained via [`tf.contrib.distributions.fill_triangular`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/distributions/fill_triangular), and are being multiplied (along with an appropriate transpose on one of them) to obtain covariance matrices associated to each spatial coordinate. I don't know if that helps in any way, but it gives some context at the very least. Also, there might or might not be a batch dimension as well, but I'm assuming that solving the 4-D tensor case would be generalizable enough.

Comment: `np.matmul` is exacly what your looking for

Comment: `np.matmul` will broadcast and give you the right shape. But it seems that didn't work for you. What was the problem with it?

Comment: If I read your dimensions right, the numpy `matmul` should work `A@B`.  This is the kind of `stack of matrices` that it's designed to handle.  So would `np.einsum('ijkl,ijlm->ijkm',A,B)`.  But I don't know what `tf` has for this.

Comment: Goodness. You're all right. I was so busy assuming my code is ok and looking for solutions, bu you guys made me look much more closely and it seems I was doing something wrong :-( 
That comes to show something! I don't know what though, so I'll just fix my code and keep going...
(I had an extra size-1 redundant dimension on one of my tensors, and the ValueError was pointing at other dimensions and  threw me off). 
 
So I was being dumb after all. Should have known. Thanks all the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this for future reference:
From numpy `matmul` doc:

> If either argument is N-D, N > 2, it is treated as a stack of matrices
>   residing in the last two indexes and broadcast accordingly.

For dimensions `>2` it will treat it as a stack of matrices, attempting to `matmul` the last 2 dimensions, resulting with a `np array` as the OP required.
For example:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.ones((1,2,1,2))
B = np.ones((1,2,2,1))

print(A.shape)
print(B.shape)
print(np.matmul(A,B).shape)
```

with result:

```
(1, 2, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 2, 1)
(1, 2, 1, 1)
```